How do I resolve an issue that prevents an SQL file from running on MySQL Workbench?
Note: I’m a complete beginner to SQL, and while I have coded before in other languages, I am confused with different things like the terms “instance” and "tab" and the concept of connection in this situation, so I might use it in the wrong way.
I'm following Programming with Mosh's SQL Tutorial for Beginners [Full Course] on YouTube, and he provided a link that downloads some course materials. He opens 'create-databases' in MySQL Workbench easily (17:26 in the video), but when I click 'create-databases' in my Windows File explorer, MySQL Workbench makes another unconnected tab instead of just working with the Local instance MySQL80 tab. My problem is that there seems to be a connection issue that is preventing the thunderbolt run icon from being clickable. I want to be able to run the SQL file in MySQL Workbench.

MySQL Workbench seems to be connected to my local instance.

How do I run the SQL file on MySQL Workbench?
I made sure that I was running on the local instance tab, but when I opened the 'create-databases' SQL file from File Explorer, MySQL Workbench created another tab and doesn't allow me to run the SQL script.

Do you have a local MySQL server running? How did you start it?

I don't think your mysql workbench is connected to a database, as the left-hand side windows are all blank on the first screenshot. Did you make a connection and logged in before trying to open the sql file?
